# QT QQuickPaintedItem grabToImage() ready signal not called consistently

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My application is written in **QML** and I'm trying to create my own efficient canvas control (with efficient flood fill). After searching a lot I've found that the way of doing this efficiently is to write a **QTQuick** plugin with a class deriving from **QQuickPaintedItem** and override paint() function.

In order to implement the painting in paint (and supporting Undo Redo history), at the end of the paint() method in the derived class I call **grabToImage**() on the instance of the object and connect the **grabToImageResult::ready()** signal to a public slot in my class in which I'm receiving the rendered image and push it into a stack container.

However, my problem is that sometimes the grabToImageResult::ready() is called before the next paint() function call (as a result of the user painting the next shape) and sometimes after and this causes artifacts to the painting because in the next paint() I first call **painter->drawImage()** with the last grabbed image and then painting the new shape right after.

Is there a way to force this asynchronous function (grabToImage()) to emit the ready() signal more consistently (always before the next paint() call)?

Thank you

Comment: you might need a bool ```IsPaintReady``` that is set after your ready signal. in your paint method check for this flag before drawing your new shapes?

Comment: The problem is that it does not matter how much time I wait until the next drawing, the ready() signal consistently fired after 2 new paint() invocations , for example if I use the Pen tool and call draw path when mouse moves, only after 2 invocations of the new Pen painting the ready() signal from the previous painting operation (like the previous Pen) is fired.